# Webpack and rxjs - "You may need an appropriate loader" error

Tags: typescript, webpack, rxjs, ts-loader

I've just installed rxjs with npm into my typescript project.

After including `import {take, map} from "rxjs/operators"` into one file, any subsequent attempt at `npx webpack` fails and gives many instances of the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/util/noop.d.ts 1:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export declare function noop(): void;
| //# sourceMappingURL=noop.d.ts.map
 @ ./node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/index.d.ts 23:0-44 23:0-44
```

For reference, here is the `noop.d.ts.map` file causing the issue (this is one of many similar ones). The issue I guess occurs right at the `declare` token:

```
export declare function noop(): void;
//# sourceMappingURL=noop.d.ts.map
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader'
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.d.ts'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

My installed dependencies in `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.76.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security"
  }
```

Any idea how to get past this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Updated with my `tsconfig.json`

```
{  
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es6",
        "lib": ["DOM", "ES6", "DOM.Iterable", "ScriptHost", "ES2016.Array.Include"],
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "noEmit": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use dts-loader to resolve that error.

```
npm install --save-dev dts-loader
```

Then in your `webpack.config.js` add this in the rules

```
{
    test: /\.d\.ts$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'dts-loader'
    }
}
```

Edit: try ignoring d.ts files by changing it to this

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader'
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.d.ts'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.d\.ts$/),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

Comment: That worked quite well, thanks. But now the error was upgraded to "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders." And it still complains about the "declare" keyword

Comment: I'm wondering if you could just ignore .d.ts files, put your code back to how it was and add this to module exports above the output section:           plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.d\.ts$/),
  ],

Comment: I've edited my answer with the full code to try and ignore d.ts files

Comment: Sadly, nothing happens. It gives the same error as my previous comment :/

Comment: Removing ts-loader and adding test: /\.d\.ts|tsx?$/ to dts-loader seems to progress it a little. Now the error is "Unexpected token at let table: HtmlTableElement;" A completely random location for an error

Answer (score 1):

First, your import should be:

```js
import {take, map} from "rxjs"
```

note that "rxjs/operators" is deprecated.

Second, remove ".d.ts" from the list of resolve extensions in your webpack config.

Finally, show your tsconfig.json contents.  The error might be in there.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I tried as instructed but still nothing. I have updated the original question with my tsconfig.json

Comment: @AndrejButić so the only thing I can think of is: what is importing noop.d.ts.  Trace that back to which of your app code imports is causing this.  You are getting this error because *something* is importing some .d.ts files which is making webpack try to bundle it.  But of course you exclude anything from node_modules from being transpiled (which is the way it should be).  Make sure you don't have an accidental import of an rxjs .d.ts file somewhere in your code.

Comment: a good way to debug it is to go into your entry point (app.js) and COMMENT EVERYTYHING OUT...all the imports, all the code EVERYTHING so that it is basically an empty file.  Then add just `import {map} from "rxjs"; (globalThis as any).foo = map;` and see if that compiles.  If it does, then you know it is something in your code and you can use this methodology to slowly add back imports until you find the culprit.